# Laravel passport returning same user details though different users logged in

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, axios, laravel-passport, php-7.1

I am using Laravel passport for API authentication using password grant type.

Api is running at : `localhost:80` ( laravel 5.4)

UI is running at: `localhost: 8080` (using axios & vuejs)

I have 4 users in my system. so based on who logged-in, i need to return logged-in user abilities

I am able to generate access_token using email & password

but `Auth::user()` is always returning 1st user though i logged-in with other users???

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the problem was incorrect role was assigned to all users, that was the problem.

Comment: Hi, How did you solve that I'm kinda have same issue but in resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833283/how-to-get-current-user-information-in-laravel-resources-from-api-route